# Trouble Using the preg_replace Option

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex:

```
preg_match_all('#^(((?:-?>?(?:[A-Z]{3})?\d{3})+)-([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})-\n\/O.([A-Z]{3}).KCLE.([A-Z]{2}).([A-Z]).([0-9]{4}).[0-9]{6}T[0-9]{4}Z-([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4}T[0-9]{4}Z[\/]))#', '', $matches)
```

that runs against a string(s) on a webpage. An example of a possible string:

```
OHZ012>018-PAZ015-060815-
/O.EXP.KCLE.BH.S.0015.000000T0000Z-170806T0700Z/
```

This will correctly match the string. However, for `$matches[2]` it will output

OHZ012>018-PAZ015

I want this line to read: 012>018-015 (i.e. remove the letters from that group).

I have tried the following using preg_replace:

```
$matches = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3})/','',$matches);
```

Now if I print out `$matches[2]` it just gives me the 3rd character as opposed to the group. So for example, it will print out "2" instead of "012>018-015". Any idea why it isn't printing out the entire group as I would expect?

Comment: That would be simpler. But I'm not exactly sure how I would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all` populates your `$matches` variable with an array of arrays. The third parameter of `preg_replace` should be either a string or an array of strings, so that is probably where you were running into the issue.

`$matches[2]`, however, *is* an array of strings, so you can call `preg_replace` passing it as the third parameter and get your results.

```
$matches[2] = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3})/','',$matches[2]);
```

If you would like a more generic letter replacement regex, you can use `/[A-Z]/i` to remove all letters in the strings.